# Why my SVG calling doesn't work?

Tags: css, svg

I'm studying SVG files (beginning) but I can't make my SVG appear when I set `<defs>` tag!

I mean.. If I call the SVG directly it works properly.

Like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="163.514px" height="263.514px" viewBox="0 0 163.514 263.514" enable-background="new 0 0 163.514 263.514"
     xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <rect class="bosta1" y="55.406" fill="#E8CF1E" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="163.514" height="137.838"/>
    <rect class="bosta2" x="62.162" fill="#E42326" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="44.811" height="263.514"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sz0bkbdm/

But if I try to use refs I can't make the rects visible.

Like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="mySvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="163.514px" height="263.514px" viewBox="0 0 163.514 263.514" enable-background="new 0 0 163.514 263.514"
     xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
<g>

    <rect class="ret1" y="55.406" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="163.514" height="137.838"/>
    <rect class="ret2" x="62.162" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="44.811" height="263.514"/>

</g>
</defs>
</svg>

MY CONTENT

<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#mySvg"></use>
</svg>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1hdLy82/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="mySvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="163.514px" height="263.514px" viewBox="0 0 163.514 263.514" enable-background="new 0 0 163.514 263.514"
     xml:space="preserve">
<defs>   
    <rect id="ret1" y="55.406" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="163.514" height="137.838"/>
    <rect id="ret2" x="62.162" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="44.811" height="263.514"/>
</defs>
</svg>

MY CONTENT

<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#ret1"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#ret2"></use>
</svg>
```

and the css is:

```
#mySvg { width:100px; height:auto; }
#ret1 { fill:green; stroke:red; }
#ret2 { fill:blue; stroke:white; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are exchanging `<refs>` with `<defs>`, since i have never heard of a `<refs>` tag before.

**UPDATE**

remove the wrong `refs/defs`, than it works!

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weg7ebtn/1/)

**UPDATE #2**

Well ok, than like so:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
       <g id="toshow">
           <rect class="ret1" y="55.406" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="163.514" height="137.838"/>
           <rect class="ret2" x="62.162" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="44.811" height="263.514"/>

       </g>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#toshow"></use>
</svg>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/weg7ebtn/4/)

**UDDATE #3**

Probably [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798890/how-can-i-reference-a-radialgradient-from-a-different-inline-svg-element).

Comment: But if I remove the image will appear two times! I'd like to set the SVG inline and call using the "<use>" tag posteriorly.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is here please follow this code

```
<svg version="1.1" id="mySvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<defs>
<g>

    <rect id="ret1" y="55.406" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="163.514" height="137.838"/>
    <rect id="ret2" x="62.162" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="44.811" height="263.514"/>

</g>
</defs>
</svg>

MY CONTENT

<svg >
    <use xlink:href="#ret1"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#ret2"></use>
</svg>
```

or

```
<svg version="1.1" id="mySvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<defs>
<g id="rec1">

    <rect id="ret1" y="55.406" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="163.514" height="137.838"/>
    <rect id="ret2" x="62.162" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="44.811" height="263.514"/>

</g>
</defs>
</svg>

MY CONTENT

<svg >
    <use xlink:href="#rec1"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: you need modify your SVG as well as it's not rect see, this for example <svg  width="163.514px" height="263.514px" viewBox="0 0 163.514 263.514" enable-background="new 0 0 163.514 263.514">